# Twitter Status update with URL - bypassing app ad?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I setup a simple twitter status update option in an app on my iPad. All it does is launches a browser with a URL that will pre-fill the status (http://twitter.com/?status=test). Unfortunately, Twitter places an ad for the iPad app right there. I'm sure if my user hits "Continue to mobile.twitter.com" they won't see it again, but is there a way to skip it completely? I'm hoping I can throw a variable into the URL to skip it?

Comment: I doubt removing a source of revenue for Twitter _on a Twitter page_ will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing they are user-agent sniffing, so perhaps you could change the `User-Agent` setting (if you have control over it) so the device does not advertise itself as an iPad?

If they don't think its an iPad, they probably won't show the iPad ad, and you should be all set.